# TVD slope / flux limiters formulation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, finite-volume, hyperbolic-pde, flux-limiters

Even if the formulation is the same the [TVD slope limiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux_limiter) can be applied:

- to state reconstruction at the interface, in 1D FV formulation, we reconstruct the $Q^*_{j+1/2}$ and the $Q^*_{j-1/2}$ in the formulation:
  $$
  Q_J^{n+1}=Q_J^n+\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}\left[F\left( Q^*_{j+1/2}\right)- F\left( Q^*_{j-1/2}\right)\right]
  $$
  where: $$Q^*_{j-1/2} = Q_{j-1}+\phi\left(Q_j-Q_{j-1}\right)  $$
  $$Q^*_{j+1/2} = Q_{j+1}+\phi\left(Q_{j+1}-Q_{j}\right)  $$
  (formulation took from [this book)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131274988)
- For mixing up different numerical fluxes of different order. And hence approximating directly the fluxes as: $$ F \left( u_{i + \frac{1}{2}} \right) = f^{low}_{i + \frac{1}{2}}  - \phi\left( r_i \right) \left( f^{low}_{i + \frac{1}{2}}  - f^{high}_{i + \frac{1}{2}}  \right)$$
  $$F \left( u_{i - \frac{1}{2}} \right) = f^{low}_{i - \frac{1}{2}}  - \phi\left( r_{i-1} \right) \left( f^{low}_{i - \frac{1}{2}}  - f^{high}_{i - \frac{1}{2}}  \right)  $$
  (formulation took from [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0750665947) or [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b79761))

I see a strong difference that is in the nature of the numerical fluxes raising from the two cases. In the first case the numerical fluxes are built by a left and a right state raising from a linear approximation of the two state. In the second case I can have a purely [Godunov method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godunov%27s_scheme), and hence a purely piecewise approximation of left and right state, but the TVD flux helps in the treatment of the discontinuity and avoid the oscillations in proximity of that. Hence 2 questions:

- Is it the only the [TVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_diminishing) property in common with the two methods just cited?
- Is it in case possible to combine the TVD reconstruction (first case) with TVD flux (second case) even with different slope/flux limiters?